# how do i access session using app.js in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, session

I am fairly new to node.js and i developed an application that requires me to send mail to users. I am using the session to store the user's "username".So, I wrote a controller for sending mail to users. Below is the code,

**mailcontroller.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var email = require('nodemailer');
var node = require('node-schedule');



mongoose.connect("URL",{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
var pro = mongoose.model('signup');


var sendEmail = node.scheduleJob('*/60 * * * *', function(){
  pro.find({username:"#I NEED SESSION OBJECT'S KEY HERE"},function(err,data){
//logic
 }
};
```

below is my **app.js** file

```
var mailcontroller = require('./controllers/mailcontroller');
var session = require('express-session');
var redis = require('redis');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var client  = redis.createClient();

var app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'shhhhh',
  store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl : 260}),
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false
}));

app.set('view engine','ejs');


app.use('/assets',express.static('./public/assets')); 
mailcontroller();
//listen to port


app.listen(3000);
```

**Is there a way to access the session's username using the app instead of req?** because I cannot afford to write

```
module.exports = function(app){
  app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var sendEmail = node.scheduleJob('*/60 * * * *', function(){
      pro.find({username:"varunreddy"},function(err,data){
  });
};
```

in **mailcontroller** BECAUSE it will only schedule mails only when user logs in!.

Answer (score 1):

Please use following command for get session following 
   Ssn= req.session;
  Ssn.client;